# keyboard keeps resetting itself to U.S

Tags: internationalization

I have a British keyboard which I have set in my keyboard preferences, however my mac keeps resetting itself back to U.S.

[image]

This annoying feature happens about 5 to 10 times a day.  How can I permanently set the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in your keyboard preferences whether you have more than one language setting. If so remove the unwanted language.

Also check In system settings -> Language & Region whether are more than one language is setting. Remove all unless your main language.

Test if works.

Answer (score 2):

The default key command to switch Input Sources is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>space</kbd>  which you may be triggering accidentally.
From comments, I understand the new default since El Capitan is  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>space</kbd> , however it also appears it will remain at the old setting if you upgraded from an older OS.

To remove unwanted input sources go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources & remove all except the one you wish to keep.

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to keep the other sources but not trigger them accidentally, then remove the shortcuts in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Input Sources. [This option is only visible if you have more than one source in the previous pref pane.]

[image]

With the key command to change sources removed, you can change from the menu bar flag.

If you remove all except one source, the flag icon will disappear.

Comment: Starting with El Capitan the default is actually Control plus Space (as also in iOS 9).  But I think some users wind up with Command plus Space via their upgrading process....

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks Tom - mine is probably legacy; long series of in-place upgrades. I'll add it to the answer.